# Isotope adds random styling to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, filtering, jquery-isotope

I've got a problem with isotope.js

I got a grid, where I want to filter images.

```
<div id="grid" class="grid">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 crop">
    <div class="item krankenhaus">
      <img src="assets\images\cons1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now isotope adds random styling to the grid and destroys my whole image gallery. The following is being added by isotope to the grid div:

```
style="position: relative; height: 80px;"
```

Why does it do this? I used isotope before and just copied my isotope code.

Comment: ok I see WHY it does add styling. Obviously it needs to do this to display the filtered items. But why does it take height 80px as default?

Comment: Why aren't you filtering your elements ***before*** passing them to Isotope?

Comment: That's the default height setting given by isotope styles if nothing is given. They get preloaded when you start the application.